# Chat-bot Pop Up not appearing when I click on Button

Tags: python, html, css, bots, chatbot

I am currently following a YouTube tutorial on how to build a chatbot using Python and JavaScript. I have managed to implement the chat button on my website, but when I click it, the chatbot pop-up does not appear as expected.

I have provided the relevant code below, here is app.js:

```
class Chatbox {
  constructor() {
    this.args = {
      openButton: document.querySelector(".chatbox__button"),
      sendButton: document.querySelector(".send__button"),
    };

    this.state = false;
    this.messages = [];
  }

  toggleState(chatBox) {
    chatBox.classList.toggle("chatbox--active");
  }

  onSendButton(chatBox) {
    var textField = chatBox.querySelector("input");
    let text1 = textField.value;
    if (text1 === "") {
      return;
    }

    let msg1 = { name: "User", message: text1 };
    this.messages.push(msg1);

    fetch($SCRIPT_ROOT + "/predict", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: text1 }),
      mode: "cors",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then((r) => {
        let msg2 = { name: "Sam", message: r.answer };
        this.messages.push(msg2);
        this.updateChatText(chatBox);
        textField.value = "";
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
        this.updateChatText(chatBox);
        textField.value = "";
      });
  }

  updateChatText(chatBox) {
    var html = "";
    this.messages
      .slice()
      .reverse()
      .forEach(function (item, index) {
        if (item.name === "Sam") {
          html +=
            '<div class="messages__item messages__item--visitor">' +
            item.message +
            "</div>";
        } else {
          html +=
            '<div class="messages__item messages__item--operator">' +
            item.message +
            "</div>";
        }
      });

    const chatMessage = chatBox.querySelector(".chatbox__messages");
    chatMessage.innerHTML = html;
  }

  display() {
    const { openButton, sendButton } = this.args;
    const chatBox = document.querySelector(".chatbox");

    openButton.addEventListener("click", () => this.toggleState(chatBox));

    sendButton.addEventListener("click", () => this.onSendButton(chatBox));

    const inputNode = chatBox.querySelector("input");
    inputNode.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
      if (event.key === "Enter") {
        this.onSendButton(chatBox);
      }
    });
  }
}

const chatbox = new Chatbox();
chatbox.display();
```

The display() method is responsible for attaching event listeners to the chat button and handling the chatbox toggle functionality. However, when I click the button, nothing happens.

Here is an image of my website:

Here is my html code base for 'base.html':

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Chatbot</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="chatbox">
        <div class="chatbox__support">
            <div class="chatbox__header">
                <div class="chatbox__image--header">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/circled-user-female-skin-type-5--v1.png" alt="image">
                </div>
                <div class="chatbox__content--header">
                    <h4 class="chatbox__heading--header">Chat support</h4>
                    <p class="chatbox__description--header">Hi. My name is Sam. How can I help you?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="chatbox__messages">
                <div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="chatbox__footer">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Write a message...">
                <button class="chatbox__send--footer send__button">Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chatbox__button">
            <button><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/chatbox-icon.svg') }}" /></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var $SCRIPT_ROOT = "{{ request.script_root|tojson }}";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='app.js') }}"></script>

</body>
</html>
and here is my css code base for style.css:

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 100%;
    background: #F1F1F1;
}

*, html {
    --primaryGradient: linear-gradient(93.12deg, #581B98 0.52%, #9C1DE7 100%);
    --secondaryGradient: linear-gradient(268.91deg, #581B98 -2.14%, #9C1DE7 99.69%);
    --primaryBoxShadow: 0px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    --secondaryBoxShadow: 0px -10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    --primary: #581B98;
}

/* CHATBOX
=============== */
.chatbox {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    right: 30px;
}

/* CONTENT IS CLOSE */
.chatbox__support {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: #eee;
    width: 300px;
    height: 350px;
    z-index: -123456;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

/* CONTENT ISOPEN */
.chatbox--active {
    transform: translateY(-40px);
    z-index: 123456;
    opacity: 1;

}

/* BUTTON */
.chatbox__button {
    text-align: right;
}

.send__button {
    padding: 6px;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}


/* HEADER */
.chatbox__header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background: orange;
}

/* MESSAGES */
.chatbox__messages {
    margin-top: auto;
    display: flex;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.messages__item {
    background: orange;
    max-width: 60.6%;
    width: fit-content;
}

.messages__item--operator {
    margin-left: auto;
}

.messages__item--visitor {
    margin-right: auto;
}

/* FOOTER */
.chatbox__footer {
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0;
}

.chatbox__support {
    background: #f9f9f9;
    height: 450px;
    width: 350px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}

/* HEADER */
.chatbox__header {
    background: var(--primaryGradient);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: var(--primaryBoxShadow);
}

.chatbox__image--header {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.chatbox__heading--header {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    color: white;
}

.chatbox__description--header {
    font-size: .9rem;
    color: white;
}

/* Messages */
.chatbox__messages {
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.messages__item {
    margin-top: 10px;
    background: #E0E0E0;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    max-width: 70%;
}

.messages__item--visitor,
.messages__item--typing {
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

.messages__item--operator {
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    background: var(--primary);
    color: white;
}

/* FOOTER */
.chatbox__footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    background: var(--secondaryGradient);
    box-shadow: var(--secondaryBoxShadow);
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.chatbox__footer input {
    width: 80%;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    text-align: left;
}

.chatbox__send--footer {
    color: white;
}

.chatbox__button button,
.chatbox__button button:focus,
.chatbox__button button:visited {
    padding: 10px;
    background: white;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 50px;
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on why the chatbot pop-up is not appearing when the button is clicked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within display() method,

try changing A to B

A

```
const chatBox = document.querySelector(".chatbox");
```

B

```
const chatBox = document.querySelector(".chatbox__support");
```

Comment: OMG THANK U !!! <333 IT WORKS YAY :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped! And please adopt an answer so that others can see that this question has been solved :)